# Распределение API функций между http и websoket

Tags: http, websocket

У меня есть приложение которое использует для связи с сервером и http и websoket
Изначально http использовался для авторизации пользователей, подгрузки изображений и тд, а websoket`ы были добавлены для оповещения о новых уведомлениях
Сейчас мне надо добавить ряд разношерстных api методов и возникает вопрос, какие из них стоит реализовывать через http, а какие через сокеты
А именно по какому критерию их стоит распределять?
Стоит ли оставить ws только для оповещений о чем либо, или имеет смысл также использовать его для небольших api методов?

Comment: WS - для получение "свежей" информации, которая нужна в реальном времени. Статику же по http. Постоянно обновляющаяся лента новостей, какие-то уведомления, это всё в WS, а если там та же авторизация, та же статическая информация которая обновляется очень редко, то http. Будь то какая-то запись, информация и т.д.

Comment: я бы, чтоб не городить огород, на сокетах только служебный "пуш" оставил - типа обновился блок С3, займись... а все остальное стандартно. почему: чтоб не дублировать функции в первую очередь.